# Support on creating appscript for google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Quite new to making appscripts and I am currently very basic with Javascript so I am trying to better my knowledge and understanding.

My current problem is that I have 3 sheets, 1 is a connector to salesforce that refreshes every 24h to pull through data over the last 7 day period. I have made a 2nd sheet (sheet2) which sorts that data by column A (date) and column B (date/time), I have then added in a filter to only pull through yesterday's data based on cell value "=TODAY() -1". The third sheet I have created is to have manual input from my colleagues in new additional rows.

I am trying to design a script that will add in new rows based on the criteria "=TODAY() -1" in sheet3 and add to new rows of this data when executed, so I can create a simple Button with the script attach to do this rather than copying and pasting over this set of data.

Again - apologies if this is something which is quite simple, I have been learning javascript for less than 2 weeks :)

I have not yet tried anything

Comment: Let me see if I have it.  Sheet 2 has a copy of the rows from yesterdays Sheet1.  Isn't sheet 2 the same as Sheet1?  Now in Sheet3 you want to add rows for user input based on the rows that are copied from Sheet1?  I'm assuming someting from the new Sheet2 rows is in the new rows in Sheet3?

Comment: Sheet 1 - Salesforce connector that has 5 columns, A=Date, B=DATE/TIME, C/D/E specific criteria, this will automatically populate new data every 24h and only populates the last 7 days of data, so cells change constantly. Sheet 2 - Sorts by Column A, Then Column B ascending (earliest date at top, latest further down) based on criteria =TODAY() - 1 (So yesterday's data). Sheet3 - I want to run a script that will copy and past over Yesterdays data in sheet 2 for Columns A-E, I do not want this data to be deleted, but when executed, new data is added under previous days data

Comment: So Sheet2 is only Yesterdays data?  Sheet3 is cumulative data?

Comment: Yes sheet3 cumulative data :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this will do what you want but its a start.  This script can be linked to a button or run from a menu option.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let today = new Date();
    // actually yesterday
    today = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1);
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove header
    values = values.filter( row => row[0].valueOf() === today.valueOf() );
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
    sheet.getRange(2,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "Error in test: "+err;
  }
}
```

Reference

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [Link script to button](https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20button%20and%20select,to%20run%20and%20select%20OK.)